# how to start learning database programming with Couchbase Server?

Tags: couchbase

I need to learn Couchbase server as database in my WPF application.
Kindly assist in setting the pool, bucket integration.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is the [Couchbase 10x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsrZkNSq8SE) series on YouTube, after which Couchbase's [blogs](http://blog.couchbase.com), [forum](https://forums.couchbase.com), and [documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com) should provide more detailed knowledge regarding the Server, clients, and mobile suite; after the initial overview the videos on YouTube provide (including a more overall introduction to NoSQL and Couchbase's